# Hello, I actually want to understand the following code. Can someone please elaborate the code what exactly it is doing. why is it crashing at line 31

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, abstract-class

I am not able to understand why is it crashing with a segment fault error. I assume it is returning an invalid pointer @operatingtrialClass(nullptr)->sum();
Can somebody explain why?

```
#include <iostream>

class trialClass{
public:

    trialClass () = default;
    ~trialClass ();

    virtual int sum () = 0;
    virtual int mul () = 0;
};

class secondtrial{
public:

    static trialClass * operatingtrialClass (trialClass * l_trialClass)
    {
        trialClass * m_trialClass;
        if (l_trialClass != nullptr)
            m_trialClass = l_trialClass;

        return m_trialClass;
    }

    static int sum ()
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        int sum = a + b;

        /*Crash point*/
        return operatingtrialClass(nullptr)->sum();
    }

};

int main()
{
    //trialClass * p_trialClass;enter code here
    secondtrial * sec = new secondtrial;
    //secondtrial::operatingtrialClass(reinterpret_cast<trialClass*>(sec));
    std::cout<<sec->sum()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `operatingtrialClass(nullptr)` returns?

Comment: Dereferencing an unitialized pointer has undefined behaviour, as is also the case with a nullptr. What's the intention of `operatingtrialClass` out of interest?

Comment: Change the code to `trialClass * m_trialClass = nullptr;` and `return operatingtrialClass(nullptr) ? operatingtrialClass(nullptr)->sum() : throw "nope";`

Answer (score 0):

In

```
static trialClass * operatingtrialClass (trialClass * l_trialClass)
{
    trialClass * m_trialClass;
    if (l_trialClass != nullptr)
        m_trialClass = l_trialClass;

    return m_trialClass;
}
```

`trialClass * m_trialClass;` points `m_trialClass` nowhere useful or safe. If `l_trialClass` is a `nullptr`, which it is, `m_trialClass` is returned without ever being pointed at something safe, making the `operatingtrialClass(nullptr)->sum();` in

```
static int sum ()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int sum = a + b;

    /*Crash point*/
    return operatingtrialClass(nullptr)->sum();
}
```

an adventure in the wild and wacky world of [Undefined Behaviour (UB)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because we don't know where the returned pointer points. Anything can happen in UB-land, and in this case that anything is a crash. It could just as easily not crash and produce a result that fools you into thinking the program is correct. Nasty stuff, UB.

How best to solve this depends entirely on what you want the program to do. You could

```
static trialClass * operatingtrialClass (trialClass * l_trialClass)
{
    static trialClass defaultTC; // a generic and safe trialClass 
    static trialClass * m_trialClass = &defaultTC; // point at the safe trialClass
                                                   // note the use of static to allow m_trialClass 
                                                   // to persist across multiple calls.
                                                   // it's pretty much useless if it gets 
                                                   // recreated every time.    
    if (l_trialClass != nullptr)
        m_trialClass = l_trialClass;

    return m_trialClass;
}
```

so that you always have a safe trialClass, but this may not be the correct option for your unspecified use case.

Side note: `secondtrial` contains no [state](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/definition-of-the-state-of-an-object-in-oop). Without state you can save yourself a bit of work and make a `namespace`.